# How to make directory automatic in nxlog server using client $Hostname?

Tags: linux, nxlog

How to make directory automatic in `nxlog` server using client `$Hostname` ?
`nxlog` client is windows m/c logs are getting on `nxlog` server but i want to create client `$Hostname` `DIR` because I have so many windows server to get the logs on that same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Output section just add

```
CreateDir   TRUE
```

Like:

```
<Output out>
Module      om_file
CreateDir   TRUE
</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CreateDir TRUE
```

See the [reference manual](http://nxlog-ce.sourceforge.net/nxlog-docs/en/nxlog-reference-manual.html#om_file_config_createdir).

Comment: but i want to make dir with ip address from nxlog client ?